# How to set a Hibernate interceptor for an EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I'm using JPA, but I need to unwrap my EntityManagerFactory, so I can add an interceptor to the Session. Afterward I want to wrap the Session back to a EntityManager.

"Why not just use Session instead of EntityManager?" We still want to reduce the impact of a possible technology migration

> For what do I want to use Interceptor:

I can resume the problem in the following way: The project works running queries on a alarms database. Each place has one database with a Alarm Table, but the client wants to have a single database, where we will have to create multiple "Alarm Table", one for each place (ex: Table_Alarm-Place1, Table_Alarm-Place2). That means we would have multiple tables for the same entity, the interceptor has the goal of changing the Table name generate by hibernate in the final SQL

> How I pretend to use the interceptor:

```
public class SqlInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private String tableSufix;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqlInterceptor.class);

    public SqlInterceptor(String tableSufix) {...}

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        String finalSql;

        //Manipulated SQL (parsed by Hibernate)

        return finalSql;
    }

}
```

- *The project uses JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 4.3.11.Final*

Comment: What does _wrapping back_ mean?

Comment: I was probably not clear enough, I'm doing "entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class)" and opening a Session with that. Now I need to "convert" the session back to a EntityManager I used the term "wrap" because of the "unwrap()" function of the EntityManager

Comment: @RafaelTeles Can you specify reason for wrapping it again for more clarity.

Comment: The project I'm working with uses JPA, therefore all code used EntityManager. I have a factory that create the instance of EntityManager that I use, if I change it to Session I would need to change the rest of the project to session

Comment: Does it really have to be a Session scoped interceptor? Can you use a SessionFactory-scoped one instead? And third, what is that interceptor going to do, maybe there are other more elegant ways to achieve this?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I can resume the problem in the following way: The project works running queries on a alarm database. Each place has one database with a Alarm Table, but the client wants to have a single database, where we will have to create multiple "Alarm Table", one for each place (ex: Table_Alarm-Place1, Table_Alarm-Place2). That means we would have multiple tables for the same entity, the interceptor has the goal of changing the Table name generate by hibernate in the final SQL

Comment: The query parsing logic is not easy, how do you intend to do it? Also, how would you read data back, for example from a HQL query like: `select a from AlarmTable`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I have no intention of parsing the HQL to SQL, I want to get the SQL generated by hibernate in the "onPrepareStatement(sql)", change the Table name and return the new SQL

Comment: My point exactly, it's not easy to do it. This resembles an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); that's why you should always state what you want to solve, not only how you intend to solve it. Maybe you should let the records be inserted in the `AlarmTable`, and then just schedule copying the records from the main table to its 'place' tables. Anyway, I think that you can utilize `SessionFactory`-scoped interceptors for this (which then apply in all `Session`s created by that factory), so the entire _wrapping back_ mechanism is not needed at all.

Comment: The last time that I give the full problem people get distracted with the context that's why I focused on my solution. I can't use SessionFactory interceptor, if I do, there's no way to specify the table suffix. The table suffix change dynamically, the may consult the Table_Alarm-Place1, Table_Alarm-Place2 or any other.

Comment: How do you determine the table suffix? I don't get why it makes any influence on decision whether or not to go with SessionFactory scoped interceptor.

Comment: Every open Session (in my case EntityManager) will be used for a sufix table, I will create a EntityManager and use it to consult the table Alarm-Place1 (for example). I have to set an interceptor for that EntityManager with the sufix "Place1". If there is a way to add the Interceptor to the Session after it is open, that would be great (this approach solves my problem completely, but for what I found out there is no way to add the interceptor after the Session is open, but I might be wrong)

Comment: Ok, but then you can write an interceptor at the `SessionFactory` level, store the suffux in a `static ThreadLocal`, and read the suffix in the interceptor.

Comment: There is another complication. I believe I did something similar with what you said using CDI, I stored the suffix in the session and inject it inside my Hibernate Interceptor. But I have a situation where in the same request multiple database (in parallel) will be access, therefore multiple suffix in the same request. But the ThreadLocal approach could work, I never used ThreadLocal I will look it up and answer you back

Comment: ThreadLocal really looks like a great solution, I'm going to test it tomorrow

Comment: Thanks @DraganBozanovic the ThreadLocal did the job. And instead of using the interceptor I overridden the NamingStrategy and now it is working like a charm! Thanks =)

Comment: Great, you're welcome. You can write what you did in an answer, so that other people can use it as a solution in similar situations.

Comment: Give me an answer so I can give you the bounty =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the necessary information in a static [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) instance and read it afterwards.

This way you avoid the complications with session scoped interceptors and you can use other mechanisms to achieve the same goal (for example with a session factory scoped interceptor which is a bit easier to configure).

Answer (score 2):

A super easy way to override Hibernate's EmptyInterceptor is to just this in properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory.interceptor=<fully-qualified-interceptor-class-name>
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can supply the `Interceptor` when building the `EntityManagerFactory`:

```
String persistenceUnitName = ...;
PersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnitInfo = persistenceUnitInfo(persistenceUnitName);
Map<String, Object> configuration = new HashMap<>();
configuration.put(AvailableSettings.INTERCEPTOR, new SqlInterceptor());

EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl entityManagerFactoryBuilder = new EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl(
    new PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor(persistenceUnitInfo), configuration
);
EntityManagerFactory emf = entityManagerFactoryBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to have a multi-tenant database. I had a similar issue before and implemented an interceptor using aspectj to set the filter properly. Even if you do not go for the filter option, you can grab te session everytime it is created using aspectj, as below.

```
public privileged aspect MultitenantAspect {

    after() returning (javax.persistence.EntityManager em): execution (javax.persistence.EntityManager javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(..)) {
        Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
        Filter filter = session.enableFilter("tenantFilter");
        filter.setParameter("ownerId", ownerId);
    }

}
```

In the sample below, I just set the filter that needs to be configured on the entity you need to filter:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "ownerId", type = "long"))
@Filters({
    @Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "(owner=:ownerId or owner is null)")
})
public class Party {
}
```

Of course, to use the filter instead of the table name, you will have to add a column to differentiate the tables - which I believe to be better than having multiple table names.

Comment: "public privileged aspect MultitenantAspect {", is this Java?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do the following:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = // created from somewhere.
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
// do whatever you need with the session factory here.

// Later in your code, initially use EntityManager and unwrap to Session.
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Basically, rather than trying to get a `Session` and then wrapping it back into an `EntityManager`, simply pass a JPA `EntityManager` around and unwrap it to `Session` on an as-needed basis.

Comment: I need to add one hibernate interceptor to the Session. I didn't find a way to do that after the session was open.